# Laravel is not accepting files in request

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I'm trying to do a simple HTML file upload.

```
<form accept-charset="utf-8" name="gallery" method="POST" action="/gallery">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="fQ7arteCHmBFVfvQARWxxK3dXNgUJF40FdsaD3R">
    <label class="btn btn-default">
        Browse <input type="file" name="gallery[]" hidden multiple>
    </label>
</form>
```

I've traced it with Xdebug and I can see that `$request->gallery` shows an array of file names but the file count is still zero:

```
if (!$request->files->count()) {
    return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'Empty file list.');
}
```

The PHP global variable `$_FILES` is also empty.

This works fine when submitted over AJAX using something like Dropzone.js, but when I do it using a standard HTML5 form element it doesn't work.

Feel like I'm missing something obvious here.

Comment: add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your form

Comment: Adding the `enctype` to the form allows the files to upload, but now Laravel is wrapping them in `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile` instead of `Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile` like it's supposed to. Any idea why it's using the wrong wrapper class?

Comment: try this .. $files = $request->gallery; then check its content

Comment: @Demonyowh `$request->gallery` is of type `Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile` but it does not contain multiple files...only the first one.

Comment: Doing `foreach ($request->file('gallery') as $file)` solved the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<form accept-charset="utf-8" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="gallery" method="POST" action="/gallery">
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="fQ7arteCHmBFVfvQARWxxK3dXNgUJF40FdsaD3R">
<label class="btn btn-default">
    Browse <input type="file" name="gallery[]" hidden multiple>
</label>
```

you are missing `enctype=multipart/form-data` in your form

Answer (score 0):

Like the other said and do not forget the [CSRF](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/csrf). (Default: on)

```
<form method="POST" action="/profile">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    ...
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

you had to check the request on:

```
if($request->hasFile('file')){
//or isset($request->file){
... //you have access to 'request->file' only here
}
```